# Xubuntu: no internet access and all network requests to IPs in the subnet are directed to me

Tags: networking, wireless-router, xubuntu

From my xubuntu I dont have internet access and it seems like all requests to my subnet (192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, . . . .etc) are directed to me.

I have an apache server installed, so when I open me browser and type for instance 192.168.0.1(router address), 192.168.0.2, or whatever , I always get that one page from apache.

Other IPs or addresses are not resolved.

**It happens only with my router**.

**It does not happen from my windows**

(It feels like a conspiracy of xubuntu and my router)

I havent done anything radical with the hosts and interfaces files. I restored them and the problem remains.

Any experts suggestions?

edit:
it seems like it happens even when networking is disabled.

these are my interfaces and hosts files (I think it might got something to do with it)

interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   gil-Spectre

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I m definitely not a super user. I solved it eventually by resetting the router(turn off and on again) but I don't understand how this issue was solved.

I would be glad if someone could give me an explanation. I would like to be able to reproduce this behavior and to solve it.

Edit:
I found out that restarting the networking service is not enough for the new settings to take effect in Xubuntu 14.04, I had to reboot. It confused me allot because I didn't see why the valid settings aren't working.